# getSku using item_id in custom table

Tags: magento

I am creating a custom module. There are two new tables.

Table1: `t1_id`(PK), `order_id`(FK)
Table2: `t2_id`(PK), `t1_id`(FK), `item_id`(FK).

`Table2.item_id` is equivalent to `sales_flat_order_item.item_id`. I am creating a custom report and in the collection need to show the SKU. At first I tried the following:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('custom/two')->getCollection();

$tbl_product_collection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/product');
$tbl_one = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('custom/one');
$tbl_two = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('custom/two');

$collection->getSelect()  
->from(array('tbl_one' => $tbl_one))  
->join(array('tbl_two' => $tbl_two),  
 'tbl_two.t1_id = tbl_one.t1_id')  
// Join with Item ID on Simple Product  
// Showing wrong SKU   
->join(array('product' => $tbl_product_collection),  
     'tbl_two.item_id = product.entity_id');
```

However, the product.entity_id is actually the product_id of `sales_flat_order_item.item_id`. How can I get the SKU in the collection, by relating to the `item_id` in table2?

Thanks for any help or suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a little bit of digging.  It helps to go to the config.xml for the core model you are looking at.  This way you know which table in the database getTableName goes to.

`$tbl_product_collection = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('sales/order_item');`
`$tbl_one = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('custom/one');`
`$tbl_two = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('custom/two');`

`$collection->getSelect()

->from(array('tbl_one' => $tbl_one))

->join(array('tbl_two' => $tbl_two),

 'tbl_two.t1_id = tbl_one.t1_id')

// Join Item ID

->join(array('order_item' => $tbl_order_item),
            'tbl_two.item_id = order_item.item_id');`